# Refreshing less on the fly

Tags: bash, kill

I'm writing a script in which I pass the output of a function to `less`, wait for some time, and then kill `less`.  All of this done inside a loop.  This makes it look like `less` is updated on the fly.  This is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in {0..5}; do
    echo $i | less -c &
    pid=$!
    sleep 2
    kill $pid &>/dev/null
done
```

This works as expected, but the terminal kind of becomes unresponsive (keystrokes are not visible for instance) after this.  What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Okay, I think the way I asked the question was confusing.  I'm trying to write a script which scrapes lyrics off a website according to the current song in music player.  The way I want to do this, I'll keep this script running in a screen session, and I want it to auto-update every 30s or so.  The finall script would look something like:

```
function get_lyrics()
{
    # function which gets the lyrics based on current song
}

while true; do
    song=$(get_lyrics)
    echo "$song" | less -c &
    pid=$!
    sleep 30
    kill $pid &>/dev/null
done
```

Comment: Why are you send less to foreground? In my opinion here is a _very_ strange script

Comment: @dchirikov Foreground?  `less &` [sends it to the background](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_do_I_run_a_job_in_the_background.3F).

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but you realize that less already has a tail mode that refreshes the end of the file? less -F (or invoke with F if already in a less session).

Comment: @metwarp Yes. Background of course.

Answer (score 1):

Create a script file and put the following in there. It will write lyrics on a file `/tmp/lyrics`

```
while true; do
    get_lyrics >/tmp/lyrics
    sleep 30
done
```

Now, send that script in the background and issue the following, which will do what you are trying to do, but in a cleaner way.

```
watch -n 30 less -c /tmp/lyrics
```

Comment: This has a problem - using `watch` takes out scrolling functionality from `less`.